# Motherboard BEEPS Code

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

I am using a Gigabyte motherboard.
Today my screen suddenly went black and the beep sound began.
I tried to restart my PC, but when it tried to boot into Windows, the same beep sound appear again.
I had to totally power off the PC and start it again to get it to run properly.

I am curious about the beep sound and want to know why my PC crashed.
The beep code is a repeating, long beep code. Something like "BEEEEEEEEEEEEP ........ BEEEEEEEEEEEEP  ........ BEEEEEEEEEEEEP".

I tried online search, but I can't find my beep code. Do you know what it means?

Thank you.

Comment: You are going to need to identify the make of the BIOS if you want to find this information. AMI, Award, Phoenix, etc. all have their own beep codes, moreover the manuals that ship with motherboards usually document them as well. But from the sounds of things, your VGA controler (aka GPU) is malfunctioning. Unless you literally mean that it keeps beeping forever, that is almost universally a sign of bad RAM.

Answer (score 5):

What you listen is the power on self test, [POST for the friends](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm).

> The computer power-on self-test (POST) tests the computer to make sure it meets the necessary system requirements and that all hardware is working properly before starting the remainder of the boot process.

You said something like... well *that like* **is** important:
it is the message that your computer is sending to you.

Reporting what found on a [*Gigabyte support page*](http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/faq-page.aspx?fid=816) it seems you have to distinguish only if your motherboard has an *AWARD BIOS* or an *AMI BIOS*.
In the first case you can refer to:

> **AWARD BIOS**

> - 1 short beep ：System normal
> - 2 short beep ：CMOS Error
> - 1 long beep and 1 short beep : Memory error
> - 1 long beep and 2 short beep : Graphic card error
> - 1 long beep and 3 short beep : AGP error
> - 1 long beep and 9 short beep : Memory Error
> - **Continuous long beep  : Memory not correctly installed**
> - Continuous short beep : Power supply unit failed

In the second case instead you can read here below:

> **AMI BIOS**

> - 1 short beep  : Memory Error
> - 2 short beep  : Memory parity check error
> - 3 short beep  : basic memory 64K address check error
> - 4 short beep  : Real Time Clock malfunction
> - 5 short beep  : CPU error
> - 6 short beep  : Keyboard error
> - 7 short beep  : CPU interruption error
> - 8 short beep  : Graphic card error
> - 9 short beep  : Memory error
> - 10 short beep : CMOS error
> - 11 short beep : CPU cache memory malfunction

References:

- A nice page of [computerhope](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm).
- The Gigabyte [support page](http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/faq-page.aspx?fid=816).
- [Wikipedia about post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test).
- [Postcodemaster](https://web.archive.org/web/20150418182131/http://www.postcodemaster.com/), a web resource with a long list of Post code and post beeps.
  <sup>(Update: a snapshot updated at the period of the answer. Other snapshots available on web.archive.org).</sup>